# How to set wifi for netplan using command line?

Tags: command-line, wireless, netplan

I am using netplan to manage my network. Modifying parameters in yaml file is easy and well documented. But how can I modify network parameters from command line?

So far, I figured out how to do it for wired network interface using dhcp4, but not if it has more parameters like wifi. It is done like this using dbus:
`busctl call io.netplan.Netplan /io/netplan/Netplan/config/FPTIL1 io.netplan.Netplan.Config Set ss "network.ethernets.lan2.dhcp4=true" "90.cfg"`
and like this using `netplan`:
`netplan set network.ethernets.lan2.dhcp4=true`

But I can't find anywhere how to reconfigure a wifi, which contains more parameters (ssid and password. Anyone knows how to reconfigure a wifi with netplan using command line?

Answer (score 1):

The netplan configuration file uses a yaml structure.

```
network.ethernets.lan2.dhcp4=true
```

is equivalent to

```
network:
  ethernets:
    lan2:
      dhcp4: true
```

looking at the wlan configuration the neded parameters can be extracted from the config file:

```
network:
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      access-points:
        "<SSID>":
          password: "<PASSWORD>"
```

And the result is:

```
network.wifis.wlan0.access-points.<SSID>.password=<PASSWORD>
```

Comment: So, it is like `netplan set network.wifis.wlan0.access-points.SSID.password=PASSWORD`? This works, but how can I explicitly say that I want dpch6? Or set static address?